# Rechart Linechart Margin issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, linechart, recharts

How to change the blank area of chart svg area?
even I have added zero for margin extra space is there. Please help

```
<ResponsiveContainer>
<LineChart            
data={this.props.getValue}
mar[![enter image description here][1]][1]gin={{ top: 0, right: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0 }}
```

screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeOXZ.png
[image]

Comment: Can you describe better what you're trying to achieve or attach an image maybe?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeOXZ.png  red marked area need to remove

Comment: Hey, have a look at this: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-shadow-rnvp8?file=/src/App.js
I have tried to address the problem you have shown the image above. If this doesn't solve your issue, I would request you to make a codesandbox and provide the link.

Answer (score 2):

yaxis comes with a default width of 40 reduce it to 20 which will remove that margin

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, it's just necessary to set `width` and `height` props to `ResponsiveContainer`. Here an example.

```
<ResponsiveContainer width="80%" height={370}>
  // your LineChart
</ResponsiveContainer>
```

as you can see, you can use % or fixed value.

Comment: I was talking about red boxed area between axis values and container box. black border is ResponsiveContainer. red big box is SVG, red small box need to reduce. https://i.stack.imgur.com/79kBu.png

Comment: Oh ok, so the css class to override is `recharts-surface` and not `recharts-wrapper`. Ok, I'm investigating...